# Can an object move with a constant velocity without balanced forces?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, friction, velocity

Can an object move with a constant (magnitude) velocity without the balanced forces? As an object which is balanced with the frictional force continues moving at a constant velocity, acquired till then.

How does an object move with a constant velocity (magnitude) on a frictionless plane (when there is no fricitional force to balance the applied force on the object)?

Can an object move with constant (magnitude) velocity without balanced forces or without the balanced forces which have been balanced by the frictional force?

Comment: If the net force is non-zero, the velocity can't be constant.  An object can't move with constant velocity along a frictionless surface if there is a single force applied that has a component horizontal to the surface.  An object sliding at constant velocity along a frictionful surface must feel an additional force that balances the friction force.

Comment: Based on this and your previous post I think you need a very basic introduction to Newton's laws of motion. Try this: 
 https://www.generationgenius.com/videolessons/newtons-laws-of-motion-video-for-kids/?type=dynamic&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_term=&gclid=CjwKCAjwp7eUBhBeEiwAZbHwkWizS3kH2-IsikzHGKkBwxseZ7yMHho8sedXg2gIjJ87VjVCaU1tZhoCM_kQAvD_BwE

Comment: Apparently OP "meant" to say constant *magnitude* of velocity (per his comments on answers). Though he seems not to have edited his question to clarify. If unedited the question should probably be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean constant velocity as a vector then it cannot move at a constant velocity without balnced forces but if your are though referring to the magnitude of the velocity being constant then yes it can move without balanced forces(an example is the circular movement of an object) As long as the movement of an object on a frictionless plane is conscerned this can happen only if the applied force is also zero.

Comment: I am referring to the magnitude of velocity.

Comment: if you mean the magnitude of velocity then what you are saying can happen if the force that is exerted on the body is vertical to the speed.

Answer (score 2):

"How does an object move with a constant velocity on a frictionless plane (when there is no fricitional force to balance the applied force on the object)?"
(assuming a rigid body) The answer to this question is, if a body is moving along a frictionless plane AND if there is a constant force, there is no way the body is moving with constant velocity.. It must have constant acceleration. If it is moving with constant velocity on a friction less plane, it implies the net force on it will be 0. If your question is how it was set into motion, then probably through an impulse or a force that lasted for a small time. In general the velocity vector for a body cannot be changed without a net unbalanced force on it. However its speed can be constant with unbalanced forced, it is in the case of circular motion where there is a centripetal fore acting. Hope this answers your question.